# Access Query Help - Get records within a timeframe of another record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking for a way of querying a table to get events of a certain type, and all events that happen within the time-frame of the criteria event for the same person. That probably sounded like nonsense. Consider the following;

[image: Example]

Imagine I want to get all "SHIFT"s for each person (A person could have multiple shifts per day) and it's associated breaks (But there could be other things as well) a way to query within a date range would be good as well. Eventually I'm going to be working with years worth of data, not all of which is necessary to everybody.

This example would return the first three rows, plus the last two. Row 5 is a BREAK, but it doesn't occur within a SHIFT for person 1.

I would love to provide some code but I honestly can't even think where to start with this one. I guess I'd need a sub query? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm mostly using access 2003 so responses geared towards that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've described the problem, it appears you want the shifts and related breaks as separate rows. To do this you can use `union all` to combine the two different types. A correlated sub query lets you find breaks that occur during shifts.

```
Select
    *
From
    Events
Where
    Event_Name = 'SHIFT'
Union All
Select
    *
From
    Events e1
Where
    Event_Name = 'BREAK' And
    Exists (
        Select
            'x'
        From
            Events e2 -- find corresponding shift for break
        Where
            e1.Event_Owner = e2.Event_Owner And
            e2.Event_Name = 'SHIFT' And
            e1.Event_Start >= e2.Event_Start And
            e1.Event_End <= e2.Event_End
    )
```

Comment: Works grand. How would I adapt this to accept more secondary events (like breaks) or only to cover a certain date range? 

I don't fully understand this code but unions look like a good place to start so thank you for your input!

Comment: I've been de constructing and it does actually make a lot of sense :)